# GCM server push fails with SSLException (Java)

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem which occurs sometimes when I send new push notifications to Google Cloud Messaging centre. I'm using Google's library available [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-server/). Im using Tomcat 7.0.35 and bouncycastle 1.46. The error occurs only sometimes and I cannot predict when. Here's the stacktrace:

```
09:05:24 [pool-18-thread-1] Sender - IOException posting to GCM
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate secret
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1868)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1826)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1809)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:582)
        at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:420)
        at com.test.push.service.impl.PushServiceImpl$2.call(PushServiceImpl.java:606)
        at com.test.push.service.impl.PushServiceImpl$2.call(PushServiceImpl.java:599)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate secret
        at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(ECDHCrypt.java:99)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:282)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:998)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: ECDH key agreement requires ECPublicKey for doPhase
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyAgreement.engineDoPhase(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.doPhase(KeyAgreement.java:551)
        at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(ECDHCrypt.java:96)
        ... 21 more
```

Anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the application running on 2 tomcats 7.0.x with Java 1.7. The problem was occuring only on one of them and was solved by changing to Java 1.6